# wrong json format after passing through ajax to mongodb

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, mongodb

Im using node.js with express and mongodb.
I have a json object like this, and i want to save it via ajax to a mongodb:

```
var somedata = {
  "Jahr" : 2016,
  "Thema": "Chemie",
  "User": "MaxMuster",
  "Fragen": [
    {"test":"test", "another": "another"},
    {"test2":"test2", "another": "another"},
    {"test3":"test3", "another": "another"}]
};
```

now my ajax function looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/SaveAltfragen/',
  type:'post',
  dataType:'json',
  data: somedata,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("data ok");
  },
  error: function(data) { console.log("error ajax");},
});
```

as soon as i pass the data with ajax my data looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584c954176f8a4219c0caeb4"),
    "Jahr" : "2016",
    "Thema" : "Chemie",
    "User" : "MaxMuster",
    "Fragen[0][test]" : "test",
    "Fragen[0][another]" : "another",
    "Fragen[1][test2]" : "test2",
    "Fragen[1][another]" : "another",
    "Fragen[2][test3]" : "test3",
    "Fragen[2][another]" : "another"
}
```

I tried to stringify before the "submit" and json.parse on the node.js server but that will not work.

Im out of ideas, i have another little app where its working but i cant see a difference.

Let me know if you need more informations.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why it does not work? What's the error?

Comment: When you look at my json object i created you can see there is an array with more objects. This gets completly lost after i send the data with ajax to the server.

After i passed it with ajax to the sever it looks like in the third code box. Thats also how it gets stored in the mongodb. (But i guess the storing part is not the problem here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it looks like the problem was at the ajax "setup":

```
dataType:'json',
```

solution is to change it to:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

Edit: and use JSON.stringify on the object before sending it via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dataType:'jsonp' or try changing the var to

```
var somedata = {
  "Jahr" : 2016,
  "Thema": "Chemie",
  "User": "MaxMuster",
  "Fragen": [
    {["test":"test", "another": "another"]},
    {["test2":"test2", "another": "another"]},
    {["test3":"test3", "another": "another"]}]
};
```

Comment: I tried changing the var but i get an error then "syntaxError: missing ] in computed property name" i copied your example.

Comment: Ther is an extra "]" at the end remove that and try, make sure that all the {and[ are balanced.